# I get a weird message each time I open the shell

Tags: command-line

Once I open the terminal , the following message appears:

```
a.a is watching you
```

How could I get rid of this message and where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely a joke by someone with access to your home directory. You can check the dots files an look for the line:

```
grep watching ~/.*
```

This will tell you the file responsible then you can remove the line:

```
sed -i '/watching/d' ~/.*
```

Done.